# yum dependency for update

Tags: yum

I have list of critical application which i don't want to update monthly/regularly. apart from those, i want to update rest of the packages. Is there any way i can exclude all critical packages and their dependency from download.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach to this would be to lock the package you want to exclude to a specific version using `yum versionlock <package_name>`.

In order to get this feature, you would need a `yum-plugin-versionlock`

```
# install yum-plugin-versionlock
yum install yum-plugin-versionlock
```

More info on this available at the man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/yum-versionlock

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422263/yum-update-all-packages/422380#422380

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page for `yum.conf` you can place in the `[main]` section of `/etc/yum.conf` a line like

```
exclude = thepackagename
```

to no longer consider the named package.  You will need to first separately identify the dependent packages, eg with

```
yum deplist thepackagename
```

and add them to the exclude line separated by spaces.